# Search epub contents with epublib

Tags: android, search, epub, epub3, epublib

I am using epublib jar file to read epub ebooks in my android application. I want the user be able to search ebook contents. I have figured out there is a package for searching: nl.siegmann.epublib.search. I found it from [here](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib/tree/master/epublib-tools/src/main/java/nl/siegmann/epublib/search). How can i use the search function in epublib?
Thanks a lot in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `SearchIndex.java`:

```
Book your_book = ...;
String your_search_word = "abc";
SearchIndex si = new SearchIndex(your_book);
SearchResults sr = si.doSearch(your_search_word);
// parse sr as needed
```